# Check if product type is in user's cart

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I would like to redirect users to an additional page in my checkout flow if they have a particular product type in their cart. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well depends exactly what you want to do, but something along these lines...

```
{% set cart = craft.commerce.carts.cart %}

{% for lineItem in cart.lineItems %}
   {% if lineItem.purchasable.product.type == "whatever" %}
       {# item of that type found...redirect the user #} 
       {% redirect 'somewhere' %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# item of that type not found... #}
{% redirect 'elsewhere' %} 
...or your default stuff directly here...
```